# three query build in one

Tags: symfony, doctrine, query-builder

I create three query build queries, I try to combine them into a single query doctrine but I do not know how to achieve
the purpose of creating a single request is to eliminate the round-trip client server. please how can I get one request?

this is my request 1

```html
/**
     * @param Analyse $analyse
     * @return mixed
     * @throws \Doctrine\ORM\NonUniqueResultException
     */
    public function countTotalErrorByIdAnalyse(Analyse $analyse)
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
                    ->select('count(a)')
                    ->innerJoin('a.analyse', 'analyse')
                    ->where('analyse.id = :analyse')
                    ->setParameter('analyse', $analyse->getId())
                    ->getQuery()
                    ->getSingleScalarResult();


    }
```

this is my Resquest 2

```html
/**
     * @param Analyse $analyse
     * @param string $severity
     * @return mixed
     * @throws \Doctrine\ORM\NonUniqueResultException
     */
    public function countTypeError(Analyse $analyse, string $severity){

      return   $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
                    ->select('count(a)')
                    ->innerJoin('a.analyse', 'analyse')
                    ->innerJoin('a.rule', 'rule')
                    ->where('rule.severity = :error')
                    ->setParameter('error', $severity)
                    ->getQuery()
                    ->getSingleScalarResult();

    }
```

this is my request 3

```html
 /**
     * @param Analyse $analyse
     * @return mixed
     * @throws \Doctrine\ORM\NonUniqueResultException
     */
    public function listTypeError(Analyse $analyse){

        return  $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
            ->select('rule.message')
            ->innerJoin('a.analyse', 'analyse')
            ->innerJoin('a.rule', 'rule')
            ->where('rule.severity = :error')
            ->setParameter('error', 'ERROR')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();

    }
```

Comment: Since request 3 has different result set than request 1 and 2, you can't. Try to rewrite your query using a UNION clause (by the way, UNION is not native in Doctrine)

Comment: @SivioQ is there a solution ?

Comment: I think, unfortunately, no. But, if your query is performant, 3 calls to database should not be a problem.  If "analyze.id" is a index, and request 3 returns a few of records, I think this is not a trouble. Check your symfony profile and see "Doctrine" section. Each query and execution time is show there.